# How to copy only visible/filtered array values to clipboard?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a worksheet of data and I want to copy a comma-delimited array to my clipboard. If I have to paste the value into a cell first, that is fine as well. The worksheet has autofilters on and is filtered. I only want to select the values that are currently visible due to the filtering, not the whole array.

The array is in column P and starts in P2. I have a LastRow set up, and have been able to get the comma-delimited part to work, but am having trouble with the copying to clipboard part and the visible values only part.

The code below creates the comma-delimited list and I can show it in a message box or something, but I'm not sure how to copy it to the clipboard or how to make sure only visible values are being selected.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim arr
arr = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Value), ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim arr, rng As Range, c As Range, n As Long

Set rng = Range("P2:P" & Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
ReDim a(1 To rng.Cells.Count)

For Each c In rng
    n = n + 1: a(n) = c.Value
Next c

arr = Join(a, ",")
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

```vb
Range("P2:P" & Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Comment: Getting a type mismatch error for this. Maybe I'm putting it into the join incorrectly? I have it like this: Join(Application.Transpose(Range("P2:P" & Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value), ",")